# I "went for" a cosmetic treatment

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

> In 2009 I *went for* a cosmetic treatment called Electrolysis.

Is *went for* correct? I'm trying to say I went and received cosmetic treatment during 2009 and 2010, but saying *I went and received* sounds wordy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, *went for* in this exact context probably *doesn't* mean what OP wants it to.

To *go for **a** treatment* here strongly implies *a **single visit** somewhere for a **single treatment session***. In this case, OP obviously had several sessions, since it was still going on in 2010.

It's possible multiple sessions were part of a single ***course of treatment***, which might *almost* license the usage. But I think that's not enough to override the *single visit* implications above.

It would be less confusing/ambiguous/contradictory to simply say...

> *In 2009 I **had** a cosmetic treatment called Electrolysis*
>    (which could be reasonably followed by, say, *...consisting of several sessions running into 2010)*

---

Note that there *is* an alternative reading (the first that occurred to me, actually). Idiomatically, [to go for](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/go-for) can be an informal usage meaning *to choose a particular thing*.

I therefore initially understood OP's statement to be implying that OP suffered from some long-standing problem (thick upper lip hair on a woman, for example). Perhaps in 2007 she'd tried using her husband's razor, and in 2008 she tried depilatory creams, before finally resorting to (choosing) electrolysis in 2009.

Okay, admittedly I decided a few seconds later that probably *wasn't* the intended meaning (because I'm guessing "Theo" is a man's name). But why risk being misunderstood when ***had*** is perfectly normal here?

---

Per @J.R.'s excellent suggestion below, and my further comment, ***had*** isn't actually correct for something that continues beyond the timeframe specified (the year 2009). In OP's exact context (with the treatment continuing into the next year), it should be ***began*** (or *started*, maybe *commenced*, etc.).

Comment: Nice catch. Having re-read the question a bit more carefully, I would suggest: _In 2009 I **began** a cosmetic treatment called Electrolysis..._

Comment: @J.R.: Spot on! I realised as I wrote the final line that ***had*** doesn't quite work for something that continues beyond the year actually specified. It would have been fine for, say, a 10-month treatment starting in Jan 2009, but OP actually specifies that it continued into 2010, which makes it a bad choice. Either *began* or *started* would work fine, though.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, what you wrote reads just fine – especially if you're talking about a single visit.

*Went* is a past tense of *go*; one meaning of [*go*](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/go) is:

> *travel or move in order to engage in a specified activity*

That's exactly what you did - you *went (for treatment).*

If you're still not convinced, look at [all of these instances found in Google books](http://www.google.com/#q=%22went+for+treatment%22&safe=active&tbm=bks&ei=y-LyUYjvOpCE9gS7zYC4Cw&start=10&sa=N&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.49784469,d.eWU&fp=4e59f00bd320ad7f&biw=1920&bih=1042). Google lists scores of hits, such as these:

> Many of the other people there were cancer victims and *went for treatment* every day.
> <sup>(from *Imagery and Symbolism in Counselling* by William Stewart)</sup>
>
> Bronson's stellar quintet of better-educated assistants included Dorothea Dix, who did not take to teaching and afterward suffered a breakdown and *went for treatment* to England...
> <sup>(from *Louisa May Alcott: The Woman Behind Little Women* by Harriet Reisen)</sup>
>
> It might be that this woman died after she *went for treatment* and Nicholas blames the staff.
> <sup>(from *Winter's End* by John Rickards)</sup>

If you're trying to say that you *started* treatment in 2009, then *went for* is probably not your best option; try this instead:

> *In 2009, I **began** a cosmetic treatment called Electrolysis*...